# Search through a database in a JSP

Tags: html, mysql, database, eclipse, jsp

I've been making a database for a flight company, and one of the requirements is to allow customers to search for flight schedules in order for them to book flights. However, when I run my code, I keep getting errors. I've tried looking through my code many times, but I still can't seem to find out where the problem is. The error message that I got was that there was a problem with the line `if(rs.next()){`, but it doesn't show any red underline when I'm looking through the code editor. Instead, the parts that have the red underlines are all my `<tr>` and `<td>` tags.

Also, I would appreciate it if someone can teach me how to create a dropdown table for the `origin_airport` and `destination_airport` datafields, so that users can choose.

Here's my code:

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1">
<title>Member Login</title>
</head>
<body>
<form>
<table>
<%@page import="java.sql.*" %>
<%
String user = request.getParameter("user");
out.println("Welcome, "+user);
out.println("<br>Account status: Member");
out.println("<br>What flight do you want to search for today?");
String origin=request.getParameter("origin_airport");
String dest=request.getParameter("destination_airport");
String depart=request.getParameter("departure_time");
String arrival=request.getParameter("arrival_time");

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
String url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/testing";
String username="root";
String password="password";
Connection conn=DriverManager.getConnection(url,username,password);
Statement st=conn.createStatement();
ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery("select * from flight_schedule where origin_airport='"+origin+"'");
ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery("select * from flight_schedule where destination_airport='"+dest+"'");
ResultSet rs2 = st.executeQuery("select * from flight_schedule where departure_time='"+depart+"'");
ResultSet rs3 = st.executeQuery("select * from flight_schedule where arrival_time='"+arrival+"'");
if(rs.next()){ 
    %>
<tr><td>Origin airport: </td><td<input type="text" value="<%=rs.getString("origin_airport")%>" > </td></tr>
<tr><td>Destination airport: </td><td<input type="text" value="<%=rs1.getString("destination_airport")%>" > </td></tr>
<tr><td>Departure date: </td><td<input type="text" value="<%=rs2.getString("departure_time")%>" > </td></tr>
<tr><td>Arrival date: </td><td<input type="text" value="<%=rs3.getString("arrival_time")%>" > </td></tr>
      <%
}
%>
</form>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could take their time and help me by pointing me in the right direction. Thanks in advance.

The error message shown on Eclipse: `An exception occurred processing JSP page [/Homescreen_Member.jsp] at line [33]`

Exception of error:

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page [/Homescreen_Member.jsp] at line [33]

30: ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery("select * from flight_schedule where destination_airport='"+dest+"'");
31: ResultSet rs2 = st.executeQuery("select * from flight_schedule where departure_time='"+depart+"'");
32: ResultSet rs3 = st.executeQuery("select * from flight_schedule where arrival_time='"+arrival+"'");
33: if(rs.next()){ 
34:     %>
35: <tr><td>Origin airport: </td><td<input type="text" value="<%=rs.getString("origin_airport")%>" > </td></tr>
36: <tr><td>Destination airport: </td><td<input type="text" value="<%=rs.getString("destination_airport")%>" > </td></tr>


Stacktrace:
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.handleJspException(JspServletWrapper.java:588)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:466)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Root cause:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.PageContextImpl.handlePageException(PageContextImpl.java:669)
    org.apache.jsp.Homescreen_005fMember_jsp._jspService(Homescreen_005fMember_jsp.java:178)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)


Root Cause
java.sql.SQLException: Operation not allowed after ResultSet closed
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:964)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:897)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:886)
    com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:860)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.checkClosed(ResultSetImpl.java:743)
    com.mysql.jdbc.ResultSetImpl.next(ResultSetImpl.java:6303)
    org.apache.jsp.Homescreen_005fMember_jsp._jspService(Homescreen_005fMember_jsp.java:142)
    org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:443)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:385)
    org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:329)
    javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:742)
    org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
```

Comment: Was "a problem with the line" the actual message? If not, what was the actual error message?

Comment: @nitind No that was a brief summary of what the message was about. I have no idea how to add error messages onto SO, and also, I do not understand what the error message is trying to say.

Answer (score 0):

The [Javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/Statement.html) for `Statement` says "By default, only one `ResultSet` object per Statement object can be open at the same time." You've opened three other `ResultSet`s before accessing the first one, each causing the previous `ResultSet` to be closed, and you can't do that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, however, I have to select more than 1 column from the database. How can I go about doing it by just opening 1 ResultSet object?

Comment: Use a single `ResultSet` with a query ANDing or ORing your `WHERE` clauses together. You already have access to all of the columns the way you've written your queries. https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_and_or.asp

Comment: Thanks for the answer. After joining all the queries together, what modifications do I make to my <tr><td> tags in order to display the results?

Comment: Get all of the column values from your one and only `ResultSet`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know I have to do that, but I'm unclear on how to format it. Could you perhaps give me an example code so that I know how to start displaying the result? I can get the result, but I don't know how to display it.

Comment: That sounds a lot like a separate question from what you started with, one less about a `ResultSet` in your JSP and more about front end HTML layout.

Comment: Yeah, I guess it is a bit far apart from where I originally started. I was just asking if you could perhaps help with it. If you can't, then I'll start a new question thread. Thanks for the reply btw.

Comment: I would be looking at Bootstrap's input groups instead of a table.